# Static method not change return data when db changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In my MVC 5 application
I used partial view and pass model through static method to get popular posts (order by viewcount), but when the viewcount of other post change, the popular posts are not change, and also the view on the popular tab.

My view:

```cs
 @Html.Partial("_RightSection",GetData.GetPopulateData())
```

Static method:

```cs
public class GetData
    {
        static UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork(new Models.AptechContext());
        public static List<Models.tb_News> GetPopulateData()
        {
            List<tb_News> lstNew = db.postRepository.AllPosts().Take(5).OrderByDescending(m => m.ViewCount).ToList();
            return lstNew;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A static `UnitOfWork` in a web project feels like an odd (i.e. not good) approach. Why are you storing `db` in a ` static`?

Comment: Have happens if you use `var db = new UnitOfWork(new Models.AptechContext());` **inside** of `GetPopulateData`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i change to create new instance in razor
and it works

```cs
GetData data = new GetData();
@Html.Partial("_RightSection",data.GetPopulateData())
```

And i removed static keyword from my method